# Register ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> using Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

How to register `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` using autofac?

I try register in this way:

```
builder.RegisterType<SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>()
       .As<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

but I get the error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
>   ....
>
> InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.SecureDataFormat`1[Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket]' can be invoked with the available services and parameters

AccountController.cs

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager _userManager,
                         IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                         ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
{
    this._userManager = _userManager;
    this._authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this._accessTokenFormat =  accessTokenFormat;
}
```

Without `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat` in constructor everything is working.

SecureDataFormat

```
#region 
Assembly Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
#endregion

using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;

namespace Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler
{
    public class SecureDataFormat<TData> : ISecureDataFormat<TData>
    {
        public SecureDataFormat(IDataSerializer<TData> serializer, IDataProtector protector, ITextEncoder encoder);

        public string Protect(TData data);
        public TData Unprotect(string protectedText);
    }
}
```

AuhenticationTicket

```
#region 
Assembly Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
#endregion

using System.Security.Claims;

namespace Microsoft.Owin.Security
{
    public class AuthenticationTicket
    {

        public AuthenticationTicket(ClaimsIdentity identity, AuthenticationProperties properties);

        public ClaimsIdentity Identity { get; }
        public AuthenticationProperties Properties { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error message explains that *Autofac* can't create `SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` could you share the constructor for it ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand I update post. This class are from owin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message explains that *Autofac* can't create an instance of `SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` because it can't find a constructor with available service.

It seems that you have not registered the required service for `SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>`. You can register them like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<ITextEncoder, Base64UrlTextEncoder>();
builder.RegisterType<TicketSerializer>()
       .As<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>>();
builder.Register(c => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
       .As<IDataProtector>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to follow up on @Cyril's answer. We have a server farm that was using a machine key to data protect so our registration, after much frustration, looks like this: (We are using Autofac for registration so it may look a little different in that regard)

```
builder.RegisterType<Base64UrlTextEncoder>().As<ITextEncoder>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<TicketSerializer>()
     .As<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>>()
     .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.Register(c =>
    new MachineKeyDataProtectionProvider().Create(
    typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
    "Access_Token",
    "v1"))
    .As<IDataProtector>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>()
       .As<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

`MachineKeyDataProtectionProvider` is a simple wrapper around the `MachineKeyDataProtector`

```
public virtual MachineKeyDataProtector Create(params string[] purposes)
{
    return new MachineKeyDataProtector(purposes);
}

public virtual DataProtectionProviderDelegate ToOwinFunction()
{
    return purposes =>
    {
        MachineKeyDataProtector dataProtecter = Create(purposes);
        return new DataProtectionTuple(dataProtecter.Protect, dataProtecter.Unprotect);
    };
}
```

And then, subsequently, `MachineKeyDataProtector`:

```
internal class MachineKeyDataProtector : IDataProtector
{
    private readonly string[] _purposes;

    public MachineKeyDataProtector(params string[] purposes)
    {
        _purposes = purposes;
    }

    public virtual byte[] Protect(byte[] userData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Protect(userData, _purposes);
    }

    public virtual byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedData, _purposes);
    }
}
```